# How to open the registry and get the specific value in c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Ineed to open this key" HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100\"

and get the "VerSpecificRootDir" value using c++ ....How can i do this

I have no knowledge abt it can any one help me in this regard..

After Getting All The Support I did it as

```
 unsigned long type=REG_SZ, size=1024;
 char res[1024]="";
 HKEY hk;

long n = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,TEXT("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Microsoft SQL Server\\100"),
                  0,KEY_QUERY_VALUE, &hk );
if ( n == ERROR_SUCCESS ) 
{
    printf("OK \n");
    RegQueryValueEx(hk,L"VerSpecificRootDir",NULL,&type,(LPBYTE)&res[0],&size);
    RegCloseKey(hk);

}
```

But in this i am not getting the value of "VerSpecificDirectory" what i have missed let me know?? what is wrong in this code....

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Windows function [`SHRegGetValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773536(VS.85).aspx) like this:

```
TCHAR buffer[260];
DWORD bufferSize = sizeof(buffer);
SHRegGetValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Microsoft SQL Server\\100", "VerSpecificRootDir", SRRF_RT_REG_SZ, NULL, buffer, &bufferSize);
```

After calling the function, `buffer` will contain a null-terminated string of the directory. Might want to check the return value for errors too.

Answer (score 2):

```
    #include <windows.h>

    HKEY hKey;
    int buffersize = 1024;
    char *buffer = new char[buffersize];

    RegOpenKeyEx (HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Microsoft SQL Server\\100",NULL,KEY_READ,&hKey);
    RegQueryValueEx(hKey,"VerSpecificRootDir",NULL,NULL,(LPBYTE) buffer, buffersize);

    std::cout << buffer;

    RegCloseKey (hKey);
```

Comment: should be in "buffer" as a char array.

PS: thanks for the fix, JIa3ep!

Answer (score 1):

I currently only know how to do that by using the [Qt framework](http://doc.trolltech.com/qsettings.html):

```
QSettings settings("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100\");
QString dir = settings.value("VerSpecificRootDir");
```

Qt is free and allows you to use simple and very good documented c++ APIs instead of the mixed and up Windows APIs. Sorry - that sounds for advertising... but I formerly struggled with the very bad designed Windows API and than found Qt, which allows me to develop faster and (a cool benefit) for multiple platforms without having to adapt my code.

Regards,
Chris

Answer (score 1):

You can sure use `ATL::CRegKey`. It has all the functionality you need.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xka57xy4(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Registry API was available (for ~15 years) from Windows 95 onwards. It's all well documented on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724182(VS.85).aspx) ; and if you care to [Google](http://www.google.com/search?hl=uk&q=how+to+read+a+registry+key+in+C) so many examples.